# error while implementing form in laravel blade template

Tags: php, forms, laravel

I am new to laravel.I am trying to create a basic form in my form.blade.php page.But when i try to navigate to my form.blade.php page i  am getting the following error:

> FatalErrorException in 5fca28a34b9eeee32d99bfd5ad77d6a463cb98c9.php
>   line 23: syntax error, unexpected 'put' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

in my route.php i am calling the View::make() method to get to the form.blade.php page

```
Route::get('/',function(){
   return View::make('form');
});
```

form.blade.php page::

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
   {{Form::open(array('url'=>'thanks'))}}

   {{Form::label('email','Email Address')}}
   {{Form::text('email')}}

    {{Form::label('os','operating system')}}
    {{Form::select('os',array(
                           'linux'=>'Linux',
                           'mac'=>'Mac',
                           'windows'=>'windows'
                           ))}}

    {{Form::label('comment','Comment')}}
    {{From::textarea('comment','',array('placeholder=>'put your comment here'))}}

    {{Form::checkbox('agree','yes',false)}}
    {{Form::label('agree','i agree with your terms and condition')}}

    {{Form::submit('submit')}}
    {{Form::close()}}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{From::textarea('comment','',array('placeholder=>'put your comment here'))}}
```

should be

```
{{From::textarea('comment','',array('placeholder'=>'put your comment here'))}}
```

Seems like you are missing a single quote.

Comment: thanks ! i have corrected it..now it is saying "class Form not found " error

Comment: Which version of laravel are you using? Is the form facade included?

Comment: i am using version 5.2.. and i am not sure it is included or not

Comment: You need to include the form facade: http://laraveldaily.com/class-form-not-found-in-laravel-5/

Answer (score 1):

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'thanks')) !!}

{!! Form::label('email','Email Address') !!}
{!! Form::text('email') !!}

{!! Form::label('os','operating system') !!}
{!! Form::select('os',array(
                   'linux'=>'Linux',
                   'mac'=>'Mac',
                   'windows'=>'windows'
                   )) !!}

{!! Form::label('comment','Comment') !!}
{!! Form::textarea('comment','',array('placeholder'=>'put your comment here')) !!}

{!! Form::checkbox('agree','yes',false) !!}
{!! Form::label('agree','i agree with your terms and condition') !!}

{!! Form::submit('submit') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Above is the correct way to use form/html, here is the documentation [laravelcollective/html](https://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html)